# tapestry apache shiro requireroles annotation

Tags: tapestry, shiro, tynamo

I tried this to prevent role doctor, and employee from accessing the page.

```
@RequiresRoles(value = {"doctor", "employee"})
```

But now, doctor and employee cannot access the page.
However, `@RequiresRoles("doctor")` works fine. Doctor can only access the page

What went wrong?

I am using tapestry5, tapestry-security(apache shiro).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I can quite understand what your question is as it is somewhat contradictory. I assume you want users that are either doctors **or** employees to be able to access the page?

From the documentation of [`@RequiresRoles`](http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/shiro/authz/annotation/RequiresRoles.html):

> Requires the currently executing Subject to have **all** of the specified
>   roles.

(Emphasis mine.) For a user that is either an employee or a doctor to be able to access the page, you can change the annotation as follows:

```
@RequiresRoles(value = {"doctor", "employee"}, logical = Logical.OR)
```